# Calling a method inside a method

Tags: ruby, any

In recreating a the Enumerable module for practice, I have `#any` figured out.

```
  def my_any?
    everything = false
    self.each do |item| #I switched this `each`. Originally, I had written `my_each`
      everything = true if yield(item)
    end
    everything
  end
```

Now, to create a `#none?` all I have to do is this, right?

```
  def my_none?
    !(my_any?)
  end
```

However, when I call the method, I get an error:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.my_none?{|x| x>2}
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
```

Comment: I can't run it.. give the full implementation

Comment: Changed it to `#each` as opposed to my own method `#my_each`. If it doesn't work, I'll post all the code.

Comment: Kevin, for `my_any?`, consider removing lines beginning with `everything` and putting `return true if yield(item)` in the block and `false` between the two `end`s. For `my_none?`, do as @Max suggests or return `false` if `yield(item)` in the block and `true` after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `yield` keyword in `my_any?`, which requires a block. You can capture the block given to `my_none?` and pass it along:

```
def my_none? &blk
  !(my_any? &blk)
end
```

Comment: ..how exactly am I using the `yield` keyword?

Comment: When you do `yield(item)`.